# How to convert a service to async service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise

below is the function that is calling service "flightPricerequest"

```
$scope.flight.blockNow= function(offer,metaData){
  SearchFlightsServices.flightPricerequest($scope,offer,metaData);
}
```

Here is my service:

```
var flightPricerequest=function($scope,offer,metadata){
    var url = webroot + 'flights/pricerequest';
    $scope.data = {
        "type"              : "json",
        "Search_cretaria"   : $scope.flight.search,
        "selectedOffer"     : offer,
        "Metadata"          : metadata,
        "EchoToken"         : $scope.flight.EchoToken
    };

    $http.post(url, $scope.data).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if(data.Error){
        $scope.flight.error=data.Error;
        $scope.sendErrorMessage($scope.flight.error);
        return false;
    }else{
        if(data == true){
            window.location = webroot+"flights/book";
        }
    }

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});       
}
```

i want to convert this service as async service so while executing service i can go withdraw the request like refresh the page should stop the service right now all actions are happening after completion of service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises..

```
var flightPricerequest=function($scope,offer,metadata){
   var def= $q.defer();
    var url = webroot + 'flights/pricerequest';
    $scope.data = {
        "type"              : "json",
        "Search_cretaria"   : $scope.flight.search,
        "selectedOffer"     : offer,
        "Metadata"          : metadata,
        "EchoToken"         : $scope.flight.EchoToken
    };

    $http.post(url, $scope.data).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if(data.Error){
        def.reject();
    }else{
        if(data == true){
             def.resolve();
        }
    }

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     def.reject();
    });  

   return def.promise;     
}
```

now call as

```
$scope.flight.blockNow= function(offer,metaData){
         SearchFlightsServices.flightPricerequest($scope,offer,metaData)
.then(function success(){
       window.location = webroot+"flights/book";
      } ,
       function err(){
        $scope.flight.error=data.Error;
        $scope.sendErrorMessage($scope.flight.error);
    });
}
```

Don't forgot to inject `$q` as dependency.

You can read more about promises..

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
>
> http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Comment: its still not working for me if i click on other link while execution of http it will not work